# How to get data from a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have to select player name, Captain name from below mentioned table structure.

table structure are as follows.

create table #temp (Playerid int, PlayerName varchar (100), CaptainId int)

```
PlayerId     PlayerName     CaptainId
--------------------------------------
1            Dhoni          NULL
2            Sachin         1
3            Rahul          1
```

I have to select player name along with his captain name from this table.
Can anybody

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are various ways to get answer of this queries like:

```
select playerName, (select t2.playername from #temp t2 where t2.playerid = t.captainid  ) from #temp t


select t1.playername , t2.playername captain from #temp t1 left join #temp t2 on t1.captainid = t2.playerid
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the CaptainId references the PlayerId on the same table, you would want the following:

```
select t.PlayerName, t2.PlayerName as CaptainName
from #temp t
left join #temp t2 on t.CaptainId = t2.PlayerId
```

If you wanted to exclude players with no captain, you would make it an inner join.

You could convert the null, of course:

```
select t.PlayerName, isnull(t2.PlayerName,'None') as CaptainName
from #temp t
left join #temp t2 on t.CaptainId = t2.PlayerId
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a self join and table aliases.

Something like

```
SELECT p.PlayerName,
 c.PlayerName CaptainName
FROM #temp p LEFT JOIN
 #temp c ON p.CaptainId = c.PlayerId
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT PlayerName, CaptainName 
FROM PlayerTable INNER JOIN CaptainTable
ON PlayerTable.CaptainID=CaptainTable.CaptainID
WHERE CaptainName = 'your query'
```

Comment: your misunderstanding the question. there is only 1 table - #temp. A self join is required.

Comment: And he might not want an inner join, which would omit players with no captain